# unity3d - byte[] to Texture kills performance

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I added the functionality to download images and make a Skybox out of it. With a loop within a Coroutine, it works fine. But at the steps

```
byte[] = bytes = null;
bytes = www.texture.EncodeToPNG();
Texture2D tx = new Texture2D(2, 2);
tx.LoadImage(bytes);
```

cost much of time and the app laggs.

Any ideas to prevent that?

[image: image to byte[] to Texture]

Comment: If you really don't need the byte data then you could use WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture. You don't need to encode it to png because www.texture returns a Texture2D. (unless you are using the byte data for other things)

Comment: Oh yes, perfect! 61ms for WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture process and 0B GC Allocate